# Creating a variable size math operator

Tags: math-operators

I need to create a symbol for a math operator that looks like `$\vee$`, with a `$\circ$` attached at the bottom vertex. Surprisingly, I could not find anything similar in the symbols PDF.

What I am really wondering about is how to turn it into an operator like `$\sum$` or `$\prod$`, which accept sub- and super-scripts **below** and **above** the operator itself.

Comment: Have you looked into `\bigvee`? It's definitely a variable-size operator, similar to `\sum` and `\prod`.

Comment: @yrodro What are this symbols for ?

Comment: @projectmbc To define a binary tree as a "join" of its left and right subtrees. I figured that this symbol is visually suggestive of the operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use a full `\circ`, because it's too big. If we scale it by half and use the bold version to compensate, the symbol can accommodate high subscripts without overlapping.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bigveecirc}{\DOTSB\bigveecirc@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\bigveecirc@}{\mathop{\mathpalette\bigveecirc@@\relax}}
\newcommand{\bigveecirc@@}[2]{% #1 is a style selection, #2 is unused
  \vcenter{\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
    $\m@th#1\bigvee$\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height\ifx#1\displaystyle+0.3ex\fi}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \scalebox{0.5}{$\m@th#1\boldsymbol{\circ}$}%
    }\cr
  }}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\bigveecirc_{B}\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty\bigveecirc_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\]
\begin{center}
$
\textstyle\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty\bigveecirc_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\quad
\scriptstyle\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty\bigveecirc_{n=1}^\infty a_n
\quad
\scriptscriptstyle\bigvee_{n=1}^\infty\bigveecirc_{n=1}^\infty a_n
$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll modify it a bit, but this is what I hoped for: A solution from which I also get to learn a tidbit or two.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternatives to have a symbol for a math operator that looks like `$\vee$`, with a `$\circ$` attached at the bottom vertex. You can see also the bit differences of height of the symbol `$\circ$`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Sequences of codes:
\[\underset{\circ}{\smash\bigvee}, \underset{\circ}{\bigvee}\]
\[\bigvee_{\substack{\circ}}, 
\underset{\circ}{\smash\prod}\]
\[\underset{\circ}{\prod}, 
\prod_{\substack{\circ}}\]
\[\sum_{\substack{\circ}}, 
\underset{\circ}{\smash\sum}, \underset{\circ}{\sum}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `\bigvee` directive may be what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\vee \quad 
 \bigvee\limits_{\circ} \quad 
 \sum\limits_{i} \quad
 \displaystyle
 \bigvee_{\circ} \quad 
 \sum_{i}$
\end{document}
```