Is there a symbol like \bigvee with a dot in the middle?
It is common to have a symbol for \cup and \bigcup with a dot in the middle. Could you do the same for \vee and \bigvee?

There are many posts that show how to create new math symbols. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505648/10898 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564975/10898

Check this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360287/10898
I simply changed \hidewidth\raisebox{-5\height}[0pt][0pt]{$#1.$}\hidewidth\cr       $#1\bigvee$\cr

A fairly general method.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\genericdot@}[2]{% #1=raising factor, #2=symbol
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\genericdot@@{{#1}{#2}{\cdot}}}%
}
\newcommand{\genericdotop@}[2]{% #1=raising factor, #2=symbol
  \DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette\genericdot@@{{#1}{#2}{\boldsymbol{\cdot}}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\genericdot@@}[2]{\genericdot@@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\genericdot@@@}[4]{%
  \vphantom{#3}%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \usebox{\z@}\cr
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{#2\ht\z@}[\z@][\z@]{$\m@th#1#4$}%
    \hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\cupdot}{\genericdot@{0.3}{\cup}}
\newcommand{\veedot}{\genericdot@{0.3}{\vee}}
\newcommand{\capdot}{\genericdot@{-0.2}{\cap}}
\newcommand{\wedgedot}{\genericdot@{-0.2}{\wedge}}

\newcommand{\bigcupdot}{\genericdotop@{0.25}{\bigcup}}
\newcommand{\bigveedot}{\genericdotop@{0.25}{\bigvee}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$A\cupdot B\veedot C\wedgedot D\capdot E$

$\scriptstyle A\cupdot B\veedot C\wedgedot D\capdot E$

\begin{gather*}
\bigcupdot A + \bigcupdot_{i\in I} A_i + \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \\
\bigveedot A + \bigveedot_{i\in I} A_i + \bigvee_{i\in I} A_i
\end{gather*}
\begin{center}
$\bigcupdot A + \bigcupdot_{i\in I} A_i + \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ \\
$\bigveedot A + \bigveedot_{i\in I} A_i + \bigvee_{i\in I} A_i$
\end{center}

\end{document}



Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.
